# my add function on client side work please assist in fixing

Tags: java, server, client

server side method with sql to add an animal name, spcies id ,animal discription to ms access data base

```
//declarations
private int port;
Socket soc;     //client socket
ServerSocket lstn;      //server socket 
InputStream in;
DataInputStream inData;
OutputStream out;
DataOutputStream outData;
static String client, username, password, request;
boolean connected;
static String model;
static Connection conn;
static Statement st;
static ResultSet rec;

//login 
static String[] ConnectOptionNames = {"Connect", "Cancel"};
static String ConnectTitle = "Set hostname";
//database and sockets
boolean isConnect;
boolean connected;

private void startServer() {

    try {
        lstn = new ServerSocket(port);
        txtWin.append("Listening on port number: " + port + "\n");

        soc = lstn.accept();
        connected = true;

        in = soc.getInputStream();
        inData = new DataInputStream(in);

        out = soc.getOutputStream();
        outData = new DataOutputStream(out);

        client = inData.readUTF();
        etc...(the rest of this code is socket close and catch statements

        txtWin.append("Connection established with " + client + "\n");
        while (connected) {
            model = "";
            txtWin.append("Awaiting new request");
            request = inData.readUTF();
            txtWin.append("Request from client: \t" + request + "\n");


    //add to Animal Table methode server side
    public boolean addAnimal(String name, String desc, int ID) {
    try {
        boolean match = Pattern.matches("[a-z]+", name);
        int count = 0;
        boolean act = false;

        if (match) /*No numbers are allowed in the animal name*/ {
            connectDb();
            java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Animals";
            ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(sql1);

            while (rs1.next()) {
                count = Integer.parseInt(rs1.getString(1));
            }

            //Check to see if the Species_ID exists
            String sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Species WHERE species_id= " + ID;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql2);
            while (rs.next()) {
                String sql3 = "INSERT INTO Animals (animal_id, animal_name, description, species_id) VALUES (" + ++count + ", '" + name + "', '" + desc + "', " + ID + ")";
                int rs2 = stmt.executeUpdate(sql3);
                return true;
            }
            return act;
        } else {
            return act;
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Server, addAnimal: " + e);
        connected = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

***the above is my server side of application this function is meant to add 3 strings inputed from client into the ms access data base. this method is called from a switch case called delegate. it works fine !!!

Next is the client side where i get the add animal error not functioning.***

//Method for adding animal in Server

```
 //sockets and stream declarations
    private InputStream in;
    private DataInputStream Datain;
    private OutputStream out;
    private DataOutputStream Dataout;
    private Socket soc;
    static private String host, server;
    int port;
    public String search;
    static Connection conn;
    Socket clientSocket = null;



 public boolean addAnimal(String name, String desc, int ID) {
        boolean fromServer;
        try {
            startClient();
            if (isConnect) {
                Dataout.writeUTF("addAnimal");
                Dataout.writeUTF(name);
                Dataout.writeUTF(desc);
                Dataout.writeInt(ID);
                fromServer = Datain.readBoolean();
                //closeConnection();
                return fromServer;
            } else {
                System.out.println("ERROR ADD ANIMAL NOT FUNCTIONING");
            }
            //closeConnection();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("ServerConnect, addSpecies:  " + e);
            //closeConnection();
            return false;
        }
    }

//Method for add button in admin add delete page/form 
 private void addbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    boolean addM = false;
    if (tabelbtn.isSelected()) {
        if (addnametxt.getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all infomation into spaces provided.\n It is important to Remember fill in a  discription");
        } else {
            addM = addSpecies(addnametxt.getText().toLowerCase());
        }
    } else {//if btn is false
        if (addnametxt.getText().equals("") || adddiscriptiontxt.getText().equals("") || addspeciestxt.getText().equals(""))/*Checks to see if all the data is entered*/ {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please fill in all details on the form.\n It is important to Remember fill in a  discription");
        } else {
         **(1038)**  addM = addAnimal(addnametxt.getText().toLowerCase(), adddiscriptiontxt.getText().toLowerCase(), Integer.parseInt(addspeciestxt.getText()));
        }
    }
```

the errors on my console
start client
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "canine"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

at mgl5client.MGL5client.addbtnActionPerformed(MGL5client.java:1038)
**(line 1038 is marked above)** 
at mgl5client.MGL5client.access$700(MGL5client.java:22)
**(line 22)**public class MGL5client extends JFrame implements ActionListener

at mgl5client.MGL5client$10.actionPerformed(MGL5client.java:392)
**(line 392)**addbtnActionPerformed(evt);

Comment: If you've got an error or something doesn't work then _you need to tell us what's not working_, i.e. what error you get or what you expect and what happens instead. We can't guess what that client method is meant to do, what `Datain` and `Dataout` are etc. - Did you debug your code? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Learn how to ask an question. You will find the link when you will start to ask.

Comment: i hope this gives better understanding of my issue @Thomas

Comment: What does `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "canine"` tell you? What is `Integer.parseInt(addspeciestxt.getText())` meant to do?

Comment: i see it means i entered a string into a box that only accepts int... silly me my data base species id is string so i can change that to int and hopefully sort the issue out@Thomas